# scalability of an 2D game with the help of openGl and some general questions

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es

i am planing to reengineer my prototype of a 2D role-plaing game to a "real product". In that case i think about using openGl instead of Android Canvas.

The reason why i think about it is because i want the game to work on devices with different screen resolutions. To do so i thought about using a Cameraview from openGl faced on an wall where my 2D gametextures are moving. If the resolution of the current device is to small for the whole game-content i want to move the cameraview so that the character is always at the middle till the cameraframe gets to the edges of the "wall". 
Is this a possible solution for it or would you rather chose a different way?

Is it even possible to draw sprites in openGl as i can do with canvas? Simply like several Layers above each other. At first the tiles than the figures with for example simple squares as lifebars (first background than the red life above it) and so on.

```
positionRect = new Rect(this.getPositionX(), this.getPositionY()
            - (this.spriteHeight - Config.BLOCKSIZE), this.getPositionX()
            + Config.BLOCKSIZE, this.getPositionY() + Config.BLOCKSIZE);
spritRect = new Rect(0, 0, Config.BLOCKSIZE, spriteHeight);
canvas.drawBitmap(this.picture, spritRect, positionRect, null);
```

If so how do i start with getting the first background and maybe first Dot(an .png picture)? I didnt find any tutorial what gives me the right kick off. I know how to sett up the projekt for an GLSurfaceView and so on.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but have you tried SurfaceView? Why do you need a the camera view?

Comment: Thanks for the question. i did actually explain it. I want to have a View that does walk with the character if the resolution of an device it to low for the whole area. I am sure its possible to implement that with the normal Canvas but i am not sure if openGL wouldnt be a better and cleaner solution for that. Aspecialy if i want to improve it more further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a bit of adjustments but it is possible and quite easy. Since you can get a tutorial and start some simple programs I will just give you some pointers:

First of all you should look into projections. You can use "`glFrustumf`" or "`glOrthof`" on the projection matrix. First one is used more for 3D so use Ortho. The parameters inside this method will represent the coordinate system borders of your screen. If you want them to be the same as most "view" systems insert values: `top=0, left=0, right=view.width, right=view.height`.

Now you can create a square buffer instead of rect as in

```
float[] buffer = 
{origin.x, origin.y, 
origin.x, origin.y+size.height,
origin.x+size.width, origin.y+size.height,
origin.x+size.width, origin.y,
};
```

And texture coordinates as

```
float[] textureCoordinates = 
    {.0, .0, 
    .0, 1,
    1, 1,
    1, .0,
    };
```

You will also need to load the texture(s) (in some initialization and only once if possible) for witch use google or stack overflow since it depends on the platform...

And this is pretty much all you need to join it in your draw method:

```
enableClientState(vertexArray)
enableClientState(texCoordArray)
enable(texture2d)

//for each object:
vertexPointer(buffer)
texCoordPointer(textureCoordinates) //unless all are same
bindTexture(theTextureRepresentingTheSpriteYouWant)
draw(triangleStrip, 4)
```

As for moving use translate on the model matrix:

```
pushMatrix()
translatef(x, y, .0)
drawScene()
popMatrix()
```

Comment: This looks more or less like i just could change the Render and the Surfaceview to GLSurfaceview and i am done. Thanks for the short introduction.

Answer (score 1):

When working with opengl, you aren't constrained to the "window" dimensions. You will define a projection matrix and viewport for your world, and then to change the "camera", you would just play with the projection matrix and viewport. If I were you, i'd pick up a book on opengl before starting this project so you are aware of how opengl works.

Also, if you are working with java then you will want to use the GLSurfaceView class. This handles all of the threading and everything for you, so you don't need to worry about it.